# Installing Pydev for Eclipse throws error

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I installed Eclipse. After which I started Eclipse clicked on menu *Help* -> *Install New software* and entered the Pydev repositories. I clicked the Pydev for Eclipse from the list of software and clicked "Next". Eclipse displayed the license information at which point I accepted the terms and clicked "Next". During install I got the following error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile955703261047833320.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile955703261047833320.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7221888664773166665.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7221888664773166665.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1224373219888388337.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1224373219888388337.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8572764312138985969.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8572764312138985969.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2639694012610278310.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2639694012610278310.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6512448876081395108.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6512448876081395108.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5072824155293786713.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5072824155293786713.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5761159553237983969.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5761159553237983969.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3878905049721471419.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3878905049721471419.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6955132184850628192.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6955132184850628192.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3372130913162820128.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3372130913162820128.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1598802442560084321.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1598802442560084321.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8546732615061650122.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8546732615061650122.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4400368409848694469.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4400368409848694469.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2092115826199391027.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2092115826199391027.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.mylyn,0.4.0.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile822829643825305648.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile822829643825305648.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature,0.4.0.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5033591236791888621.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5033591236791888621.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3861996141862945117.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3861996141862945117.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3299945087169833192.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3299945087169833192.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6118923220744193218.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6118923220744193218.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5498624301991671610.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5498624301991671610.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.2.0.201312292215.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8110807763608617052.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8110807763608617052.jar
```

Comment: I've got the same problem, even when run as sudo.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem this way (running Eclipse 3.7 on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin)): On the installation dialog, I unchecked the box "Show only the latest versions of available software" and selected the PyDev 2.8.2 version, which properly installed. I previously tried 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2, all failed.