# PyDev for Eclipse installation fails

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I'm trying to install PyDev 4.5 on Eclipse 3.7.
I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Unfortunately the installation fails with the following error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile317604218647133996.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile317604218647133996.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1653935437183270228.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1653935437183270228.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile106889934731764251.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile106889934731764251.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile9068867808045510251.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile9068867808045510251.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4356051096777669804.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4356051096777669804.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7567763792057389909.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7567763792057389909.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6685403030330680669.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6685403030330680669.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8072627041346437329.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8072627041346437329.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2089492783574675291.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2089492783574675291.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2865653197501795713.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2865653197501795713.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1775095909495668460.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1775095909495668460.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1452921649446263806.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1452921649446263806.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2451876787350801975.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2451876787350801975.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7175104755163295006.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7175104755163295006.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2106476867846363502.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2106476867846363502.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8910039705531253143.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile8910039705531253143.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1647659330788283896.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile1647659330788283896.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3781476889455217861.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3781476889455217861.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile658497740848883868.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile658497740848883868.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,4.5.4.201601292234.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2627743839460558771.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2627743839460558771.jar
```

Do you have any idea about it?
I've tried to uncheck "Show only the latest versions of available software" as suggested here "[Installing Pydev for Eclipse throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194902/installing-pydev-for-eclipse-throws-error)" but no past versions appeared.

Thank you!

Comment: Eclipse 3.7 is the 2011 release, and is failing to install a PyDev build from 2016. You should retry this on the current release, Mars.1.

Comment: The PyDev [install guide](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) says that Eclipse 3.8 is the very earliest supported version, but you should certainly go for Eclipse Mars now.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I didn't notice that I have a so old version of Eclipse. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To see older versions I use http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates I am still having troubles downloading pydev but this might help you

Comment: i also ended up using Eclipse Neon to fix this.